# My app gets installed twice on the emulator

Tags: android

When I install my app on emulator, it show me two icons of (my app) in app menu. it looks bad, help to solve this issue.

Comment: post snapshot what you are looking.

Comment: Upload the content of your manifest.

Comment: This is not the case in emulator. It will same two icons appear on the device also. You set the two activities intent-filter as launcher. This is the reason it's happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one activity in your `manifest` file should have this intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter
```

If you add this intent filter to two activities it will create two app icons. Check your manifest file.